# Stay on the current page after refresh using iFrame asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe

I am using 'iFrame' on the website, and right now, whenever I directed to the another page (says Register Page) and I click F5 (Refresh button on the browser), it will go to the Default.aspx and not Register Page. I notice that while I directed to the Register Page or another Page, the url stays on: **www.something.com/Default.aspx**, but it should be **www.something.com/Register.aspx**. I think the cause for it cannot go back to the current page is because of the URL linked to the **Default.aspx**.

ID for Main Frame is **MainFrame** and here is the code:

```
if (Session["AFFM_RoleCode"] != null && Session["AFFM_RoleCode"].ToString() == "0")
                {
// If the user is not logged in
                    if (Session["IsAgent"] != null && Session["IsAgent"].ToString() == "1")
                    {
                        mainFrame.Attributes["src"] = "BlankPage.aspx";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mainFrame.Attributes["src"] = "Main.aspx";
                    }
                }
```

How do I can solve this problem?

Your answer much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick patch you can do to this, add a session to your register page when it load, such as

```
session["Load"] = "register";
```

and when the page is refreshed, if you find register in the load session, redirect it to the register

```
if (session["load"] == "register"){
    session["load"] = "";
    //you redirect code
}
```